# How to select a column corresponding to max value (SQL - impala)

Tags: sql, impala

I checked history and there are some answers to similar problems but they seem to be too complicated.

I have table like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    SELLER_ID     MONTH     ITEMS_SOLD
1                A          201702      3
1                B          201702      2
2                X          201902      7
2                Y          201902      8
```

I would like to list columns (customer,seller and month) corresponding only to maximum items sold. The desired outcome would be:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    SELLER_ID     MONTH     
1                A          201702      
2                Y          201902
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*  -- list whichever columns you really want
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by items_sold desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If multiple months have the same maximum for a customer, this arbitrarily chooses one of them.  If you want all of them, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are a legend.